# Connect a fb Site to an iOs Fb App

Tags: ios, facebook

iam somehow new to all the Facebook app and sites stuff. 
What I have:
 - A Facebook Side bulid from my acoount with around 50 Likes and some posts
 - A Facebook App for my iOS App with will rock the AppStore next week :-)

I now realised, that I can have an App Site. So All posts done from the App will link to this site.

So the big question is: How to connect my App with the Site?

The only way I can see is to genarate an new Site out off the App and start at Zero. So please Help me

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have to do a little interpretation here:

I guess with "Facebook Side" you mean a Facebook Page - correct me if I'm wrong.
You can [create an App Detail Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#creating) for your existing Facebook iOS App. I guess that is what you mean by "App Site".

> How to connect my App with the Site?

Your Facebook iOS App will be connected to the App Detail Page automatically, so I guess your question is how to connect your Facebook Page with your Facebook App, right? If this is the case, then you might want to also create a Facebook Page Tab for your existing Facebook App. Here is the Facebook tutorial on how it can be done:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/